# Are partial derivatives of parametric surfaces always orthogonal?

Tags: analytic-geometry, parametrization, tangent-spaces

For a surface $\mathbf{r} = \mathbf{r}(s, t)$ are the partial derivatives $\mathbf{r}_s$ and $\mathbf{r}_t$ in general orthogonal?

I was thinking the surface of a sphere and in that case indeed these vectors are orthogonal at every point. We can think the partial derivatives as the tangent vectors of the curves $\mathbf{r} (s, t_0)$ and $\mathbf{r} (s_0, t)$ respectively. Can the above fact for the surface of a sphere be generalized?

Comment: Not true even for $z=f(x,y)$

Comment: This is only true whenever the parametrization is a *conformal map*, that is, a map which preserves angles.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is apparently $$\mathbf r(\theta, \phi) = (\cos \theta\sin\phi, \sin\theta\sin\phi,\cos\phi)$$
where it is indeed true that $\mathbf r_\theta \cdot \mathbf r_\phi = 0$. But notice that this a standard coordinate parametrization of the sphere. This coordinate system was chosen exactly for the property that the $\theta$ and $\phi$ coordinate directions are perpendicular to each other.

In general, this is not true. Another familiar way of parametrizing half the sphere is $$\mathbf r(x, y) = (x, y,\sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2})$$
for which we find
$$\mathbf r_x = (1, 0, \frac {-x}{\sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2}})\\
\mathbf r_y = (0, 1, \frac {-y}{\sqrt{1 - x^2 - y^2}})$$
and thus
$$\mathbf r_x \cdot \mathbf r_y = \frac {xy}{1 - x^2 - y^2}$$
which is only $0$ when either $x$ or $y$ is $0$.